# SecKeychainFindInternetPassword Prompt

Tags: objective-c, xcode, macos, keychain

I'm using SecKeychainFindInternetPassword to retrieve the proxy username and password from the Keychain Access. The app it's an updater, it looks for a new version. If the user is using a proxy I need the username and password (if there is one). The code is working but it shows a prompt asking to allow reading the key (it's an updater I do not want a prompt). The app already has administrator permissions to run.

The question is... Is there a parameter for SecKeychainFindInternetPassword to avoid the prompt or there is another function that returns the Keychain without the prompt?

Thanks,
Fiury

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This likely means that you haven't signed the app with the same key as the previous app. Generally if the app has the same signing key, it will inherit the predecessor's permissions, but will not otherwise.